# How to keep AJAX from refreshing site

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a form with dropdowns. If the desired option(s) are not available, the user should have to possibility to add them trough other forms (outside the form; not a form inside the form).

After entering a new dropdown entry (trough another form) it should appear in the respective dropdown, but all the other data already entered should remain there so that the user does not have to insert it again.

I tought this could be done with AJAX, so I tried, but it does refresh my page (somehow; at least the other form's entries are gone).

The submission of the "Insert lecturer" and "Insert module" to the database works as intened.

Is it possible to keep the data in the form?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my (simplified) code so far:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-8">

        <h2>Insert event</h2>

        <br>

        <form id="createSubjectForm" action="admin_createSubject_submit.php" method="POST">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject_name" required />
            </div>

            <hr>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Code</label>
                <input id="subjectCode" type="text" class="form-control" name="code" required />
            </div>

            <hr>

            <?php
            $lec_selection = "";

            $lec = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM lecturers ORDER BY last_name");

            while($lec_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lec)){
                $lec_selection .= "<option value=".$lec_row['lecturers_ID'].">".$lec_row['last_name'].", ".$lec_row['first_name']."</option>";
            }
            ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Lecturer</label>
                <select multiple class="form-control" name="modul_type" required>
                    <?php echo $lec_selection ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <?php
            $mod_selection = "";

            $mod = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM modules ORDER BY name");

            while($mod_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mod)){
                $mod_selection .= "<option value=".$mod_row['name'].">".$mod_row['name']." [".$mod_row['code']."]</option>";
            }
            ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Module</label>
                <select multiple class="form-control" name="part_of_modules" required>
                    <?php echo $mod_selection ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>

        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Insert Lecturer</h3>
        <form id="form" name="form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First name</label>
                <input id="lec_first_name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last name</label>
                <input id="lec_last_name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Institute</label>
                <input id="lec_institute" type="text" class="form-control" required />
            </div>

            <div>
                <button id="lec_submit" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
            </div>

        </form>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var first_name = document.getElementById("lec_first_name").value;
            var last_name = document.getElementById("lec_last_name").value;
            var institute = document.getElementById("lec_institute").value;

            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            var dataString = 'first_name1=' + first_name + '&last_name1=' + last_name + '&institute1=' + institute;
            if (first_name == '' || last_name == '' || institute == '') {
            alert("Bitte alle Felder ausfüllen!");
            } else {

            // AJAX code to submit form.
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin_createLecturer_submit.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
            });
            }
            return false;
        }
        </script>

        <h3>Insert Module</h3>
        <form id="form" name="form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Code</label>
                <input id="mod_code" type="text" class="form-control" required />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input id="mod_name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Type</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="modul_type" required>
                    <option id="mod_type" value="1">1</option>
                    <option id="mod_type" value="2">2</option>
                    <option id="mod_type" value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Year</label>
                <input id="mod_year" type="text" class="form-control" required />
            </div>

            <div>
                <button id="mod_submit" onclick="myFunction2()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modul eintragen</button>
            </div>

        </form>

        <script>
        function myFunction2() {
            var mod_code = document.getElementById("mod_code").value;
            var mod_name = document.getElementById("mod_name").value;
            var mod_type = document.getElementById("mod_type").value;
            var mod_year = document.getElementById("mod_year").value;

            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            var dataString = 'mod_code=' + mod_code + '&mod_name=' + mod_name + '&mod_type=' + mod_type + '&mod_year=' + mod_year;
            if (mod_code == '' || mod_name == '' || mod_type == '' || mod_year == '') {
            alert("Bitte alle Felder ausfüllen!");
            } else {

            // AJAX code to submit form.
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin_createModule_submit.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
            });
            }
            return false;
        }
        </script>
    </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change button type="submit" to button type="button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the form from submitting by using `preventDefault()`

In your function, pass the event and call `preventDefault ()`

```
function myFunction (event){
  event.preventDefault ();
  $.ajax(
    // your custom
    )
  }
```

On your form you need to use `onsubmit="myFunction (event)"`

Comment: Looking good! Now I need to update the dropdown. I tried:

(1)//Give ID to div:
<select multiple class="form-control" name="modul_type" required>
 <div id="lec_content"><?php echo $lec_selection ?></div>
</select>

(2)//PHP, Echo result content:
echo "$lec_selection";

(3)//Write into div with ID above:
success: function(data) {
 alert(data);
 $('#lec_content').html(data);
}

I get the desired content in the alert, but it doesnt write it into the div. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I
jQuery's `html ()` gets the html from the element. If you are trying to change the text of an element you can use `text ()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just alert()ing the returned html in the ajax call. How are you appending the returned html to the select form?

something like this should not refresh the page:

```
var modSelect = document.getElementsByName("part_of_module");

var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = 'value';
opt.innerHTML = 'option value';

modSelect[0].appendChild(opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You bind your functions to the click event of the button. It does not trigger when you submit the form by pressing enter. Instead, do `<form onsubmit="MyFunction()">` so it'll trigger whenever anyone attempt to submit form.

Remember to remove the `onclick` in your submit button so it doesn't get called twice.